# Find the least positive integral value of z for which there exists different positive integers $x$,$y$ and $z$ that satisfy $x^2 +y^2=z^3$.

Tags: polynomials

My approach is as follows  $(x+y)^2-z^3-2xy=0$ and by  applying quadratic formula i get $z^3 + 2xy >0$ but now i get stuck.

Comment: If you are familiar with Gaussian integers $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ and factorization in that, then you may want to try $(x+iy)(x-iy)=z^3$ and procced from there.

Comment: You should be careful wording your questions. "Least $z$ for which there exist different $x, y,$ and $z$" doesn't make sense. Also, I'm guessing you won't like the solution $(x, y) = (1, 0), (0, 1)$?

Comment: @TheoBendit OP wants **positive** integers. Though I agree with you about the wording.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know the [sum of two squares theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem)?  You can just start trying values for $z$.  $1$ doesn't work because one of $x,y$ must be zero.  $2$ doesn't work because the only solution is $x=y=2$ but you demand $x \neq y$.  What about $z=3$?  Before long you will find one that works, then you need to show that nothing lower does.

Comment: No i don't know that theorem

Comment: Then you should look it up.  It is directly applicable to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to brute-force (using a bit of Python code) that the smallest such $z$ is $z=5$, which satisfies the equation $5^3 = 2^2 + 11^2$.

```
import math
import sys

for i in range(10000):
    j = 1
    while j**2 < i**3:
        if abs((i**3 - j**2)**(1/2) - math.floor((i**3 - j**2)**(1/2))) < 0.001:
            print(i + "^3 = "+ j + "^2 + " + math.floor((i**3 - j**2)**(1/2)) + "^2")
            sys.exit()
    j += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

squares mod 9:

0,1,4,0,7,7,0,4,1,...

cubes mod 9:

0,1,8,0,1,8,0,1,8....

possible sums:

0+0=0
0+1=1
1+7=8
4+4=8

which allows you to search  23 out of 64 possibilities.  simply from there being 3 variables of positive value, we get z>2.  Furthermore if z is odd, then one of the bases of the squares is, otherwise they are both even.  I'll leave it to you to apply all this.